# How to get solidity-docgen to properly render multi-paragraph @devs

Tags: solidity, documentation

When solidity-docgen generates a Markdown doc file it doesn't seem to be able to properly handle a case like:

```
/**
 * @dev Returns whether `spender` is allowed to manage `tokenId`.
 *
 * Requirements:
 *
 * - `tokenId` must exist.
 */
function _isApprovedOrOwner(address spender, uint256 tokenId) internal view virtual returns (bool) {
```

This snippet is **from the OpenZeppelin ERC721 code**. The problem happens whenever a @dev comment has more than one paragraph. In those cases the resulting Markdown looks like:

```
_Text of paragraph 1.

Text of paragraph 2._
```

Note the presense of underscores. If this was just one paragraph, the rendered Markdown would be in italics (correct behavior). But with two or more paragraphs, the Markdown does not render in italics, it renders as in the snippet above (with underscores visible).

Is there any way to configure solidity-docgen so that it generates correct Markdown? Is there an alternative tool?

Answer (score 1):

Since I ran into the same problem I came up with a solution. However for me this was not enough because I need to transform the md-files into html-files in a second step.

But maybe you do not need that and you can use this approach.

Steps to take:

1. if not already done, create a doctemplate folder in your project, and put the templates you are using in there. Tell docgen that it should use this folder when looking for templates.
2. create an helpers.ts file inside this folder
3. add this function to helpers.ts

```
export function smartJoinLines(text?: string, paragraphWrap?: string)
{
    if (typeof text === "string")
    {
        // First replace all CR+LF with LF
        let modifiedText = text.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n");
        // Replace all LF that not followed by one ore more LF with a singe space
        modifiedText = modifiedText.replace(/\n([^\n])/g, " $1");
        // Replace all multible LFs with a singe LF
        modifiedText = modifiedText.replace(/\n\n+/g, "\n");
        // Replace multible white spaces and tabs with a single space
        modifiedText = modifiedText.replace(/[ \t][ \t]+/g, " ");
        // Replace LF followed by space with double LF
        modifiedText = modifiedText.replace(/\n /g, "\n\n");
        if(paragraphWrap !== null && paragraphWrap !== undefined && typeof paragraphWrap === "string")
        {
            modifiedText = paragraphWrap + modifiedText.replace(/\n\n/g, paragraphWrap + "\n\n" + paragraphWrap) + paragraphWrap;
        }
        return modifiedText;
    }
}
```

4. modify your templates to use the new function by modifying the specific lines. For Example if you want to show developer documentation you can add
   `{{{smartJoinLines natspec.dev "_"}}}`

The new function took care of multiple problems (in my case when convert to html in an second step)

- Change Windows style new line to Linux style new line
- Replace multible whitespaces with a single space since html renders them as single space anyway.
- Remove unnecessary new lines but keep paragraphs
- Wrap paragraphs with a given string

Comment: This sounds like a great approach, but could you clarify this: "put the templates you are using in there"? I don't have any custom templates, I am just running solidity-docgen as is.

Comment: I took the default templates and copied them in my custom template folder. so that I can extend them